# Annotate each query with a function of itself

Tags: python, django

I need to annotate each query in queryset using a model method:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def myModel_foo(self):
        ....
        return myModel_foo
```

I need something like `.annotate(myModel_foo=myModel.myModel_foo())`. The problem is `myModel_foo()` requires `self`. I tried iterating over queryset and using `query.annotate(myModel_foo=myModel.myModel_foo(self))`, but i got `object has no attribute 'annotate'` error. What's the correct approach?

**UPDATE**

OK, the idea is this: i have two models with single to one  relation.

```
class myModel1(models.Model):
  fk = ForeignKey(myModel2)
  status = ChoiceField

class myModel2(models.Model):

  def get_status(self):
    # query all objects from myModel1, get status of the last one and 
    # return it
    return get_status
```

Then I want to send a queryset with `status` included in it via `ajax` call.

```
qs = MyModel2.objects.all()
qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
        return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')
```

How can i access it in template then in a way like `qs_json[0].get_status`?

Comment: You can not annotate with a function call, unless you call the function, and the result is an expression like `Sum('field')` for example.

Comment: Perhaps it is more helpful if you define a concrete example.

Comment: I described it in main post update

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property to the model and don't use the "annotation" at all.
like:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        ....
        return self.bar()
```

But be careful with N+1 queries problem if the `bar` makes extra queries. You can describe your particular case and I will help you with this.

UPDATE:

There still unclear is there extra queries or not. If not, you can still use the property.
You just need the right serializer like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            # other fields
            'foo'
        ]
```

```
return Response(MyModelSerializer(MyModel.objects.all(), many=True).data)
```

Comment: I described it in main post